# .net core userwindowsservice how to pass arguments

Tags: c#, .net-core, service

I have built a windows service with .net core 5 C#

I'm using the generic hostbuilder and calling the .UseWindowsService call on the create.

```
public static void main ( string[] args)
{
   ...
   CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
   ...
}
....
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(args)
{

   Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
     .UseWindowsService(options =>
       { 
         options.ServiceName = "MyService"
       }
     .ConfigureServices(...
```

And when I run in in VS I get command line args.
But when I user SC.EXE to create and run the service I don't get command line args and it doesn't pick them up from the services control panel either.

Can anyone clue me in as to how to supply command line args?
I can get config info from the config file just fine..
But I'd like the option of specifying more 'run specific' params as desired.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm afraid not.. the args are blank coming into main when its run as a service. Thanks.

Comment: have you considered a config file as an alternative?

Comment: Thanks, yea, I am using the config file.. and its working fine.. but as I said in the question, I would like to be able to supply arguments to the service either via the command line or the services.msc properties pane... I'd like to have settings that don't change frequently be in the config file.. but have other settings to be specified on the commandline/properties panel.. et: location of file to process